# Nginx throws 504 gateway timeout while uwsgi has responded with 200

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm running a Django application with uWSGI and nginx. Everything works fine with the django development server. When I move it to uWSGI I am observing a strange (is it ?!) behavior. The request is processed properly and uWSGI responds with status code 200. The browser just keeps waiting and then eventually times out.

Here are the uWSGI logs:

```
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 10342)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 10345, cores: 1)
[pid: 10345|app: 0|req: 1/1] xx.xx.xx.xx () {48 vars in 870 bytes} [Mon Jul 4 19:33:07 2016] GET /kyc/dashboard/ => generated 28501 bytes in 7461 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 88 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

Nginx error.log

```
2016/07/04 19:38:14 [error] 10379#0: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: _, request: "GET /kyc/dashboard/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///home/ubuntu/myapp.sock:", host: "xx.xx.xx.xx", referrer: "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/kyc/login/"
```

uwsgi config

```
[uwsgi]
chdir=/home/ubuntu/myapp
uid=ubuntu
gid=ubuntu
module=myapp.wsgi:application
master=True
workers=1
pidfile=/tmp/myapp-master.pid
vacuum=True
logger= file:/var/log/uwsgi/myapp.log
logger = socket:xx.xx.xx.xx:5959
socket=/home/ubuntu/myapp.sock
chmod-socket=777
die-on-term=True
```

nginx conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    upstream myapp {
        server unix:///home/ubuntu/myapp.sock;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _;

        location /static {
            alias /home/ubuntu/myapp/static_files;
        }

        location /media {
            alias /home/ubuntu/myapp/media_files;
        }

        location / {
        uwsgi_pass  myapp;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 300;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you find any solution ? 
im searching 3 days !